# How to get a report by comparing MySQL tables in two different Databases

Tags: mysql

I have two `Mysql` database dumps (DB1_10.10.2019 and DB2_10.02.2020). I created a custom query in DB1_10.10.2019 for getting the user details and made a 'report1'.

DB1_10.10.2019:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(...)
FROM ...
WHERE...
ORDER BY ...
```

For now, I have created a table called `Table1` and stored the results.

```
INSERT INTO Table1(...,...,...)
 SELECT DISTINCT(...)
 FROM ...
 WHERE...
 ORDER BY...
```

Let's say after 4 months I want to get the user details, but this time I do not want users in report1. I want only new users. Can anyone please suggest a solution on how to achieve this?

I referred to the following site: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-minus/ and tried the following method:

```
SELECT 
    id
FROM
    t1
LEFT JOIN
    t2 USING (id)
WHERE
    t2.id IS NULL;
```

The above query works only if we have two tables in the same DB. But in my case, I have two DB's.

MySQL version: 5.7.19

Comment: What's the exact problem? Selecting data from multiple databases is not that difficult, and it's widely documented

Comment: @Sarath If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. Otherwise write how you solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the database is on the same machine and your user can access both, just enter the database name in the query as follows:

```
SELECT 
    `DB1_10.10.2019`.t1.id
FROM
    `DB1_10.10.2019`.t1
LEFT JOIN
    `DB2_10.02.2020`.t2 USING (id)
WHERE
    `DB2_10.02.2020`.t2.id IS NULL;
```

[Here](https://www.navicat.com/en/company/aboutus/blog/1059-how-to-query-across-multiple-databases) you can find some examples

Comment: Yes. As of now both the DB's are on the same machine and I followed your query and It worked.